# What does Dr. Strange summon from the Blood Bible?

Tags: marvel, comics, doctor-strange, new-avengers

In New Avengers, Dr. Strange summons some tentacle thing from a portal using a spell from the Blood Bible. It's so hardcore even Sun-God is severely weakened permanently.

**New Avengers #21**

[image]
[image]
[image]

What is that thing?

Comment: One of the elder gods, I presume. Not sure which one.

Comment: There are likely numerous powerful, unnamed tentacled horrors held in thrall by the Blood Bible. I wouldn't expect it to get a name. Not likely to be an Elder God though, they tend to be on par with Shuma Gorath and his ilk. Not easily held in thrall even by the Sorcerer Supreme. It does have Shuma Gorath's distinctive purple color however...

Comment: Is it just me or does the glasses guy look like Daniel Radcliffe?

Comment: Wait, wait! Is that _Harry bloody Potter_ there?

Answer (score 2):

Been also searching for an answer. Looks like one of the Marvel Elder Gods and/or The Many Angled One from the Marvel Cancerverse (which may actually hail from Earth-616). 
Cthulu and the Elder Gods exist in the Marvel and the Ultimate (Earth 1610) universe making appearances here and there

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any additional information that would help support your answer? Maybe an indication of which comics the other beings you reference appeared in so that they can be compared against this depiction?

Comment: Also, is "Marvel Cancerverse" actually a thing, or was that just a joke about how sprawling the Marvel Universe has become?

Comment: It is as much a thing as "Marvel Zombies" that also begun as joke, just about marvelfans.. Cancerverse is know as Earth-10011 and there were several stories in or about it in 2010, especially in the miniseries Thanos Imperative.

Answer (score 1):

What he summoned isn't explained or likely to explained.

Comment: +1. I spent a couple hours one night sifting through pics and references and reviews, and nothing I found outlined it.

Comment: If you've read Hickman's run on Avengers & New Avengers he has a tendency to leave things up in the air. For example last year the father of a member of Alpha Flight committed suicide after learning of a terrible secret, which was never disclosed or has been discussed since! There's also a second Hulk (from an alternative universe) in SHIELD captivity that has been forgotten about.